# VB.Net Timer.Tick Not Firing

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am trying to display a message on a status bar for 30 seconds when certain conditions are true. For some reason, the `Timer.Tick` event isn't running when the timer is enabled, I'm fairly certain I'm missing something on the `Tick` sub, but can't figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
  Dim StatusSecondsPassed As Integer = 0
    Dim StatusTimer As New Timer()
  Dim StatusTextField As New ToolStripStatusLabel


    Public Function WriteStatus(SS As String)


        If StatusTimer.Enabled = True Then
            StatusTimer.Enabled = False
        End If


        StatusSecondsPassed = 0

        StatusTimer.Interval = 1 * 1000

        StatusTimer.Enabled = True

        Return SS
    End Function

    Public Sub StatusTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim cMain_Form As Main_Form

        StatusSecondsPassed += 1

        If StatusSecondsPassed = 30 Then
            cMain_Form.StatusTextBox.Text = ""
        End If


    End Sub
```

Any ideas? I tried putting `Handles` on the end of the tick sub, but it generates an error if I put `Handles StatusTimer.Tick`

Comment: Bit unfair of the downvote and then no comment on what needs improving...

Comment: –1 for leaving a comment that whines about downvotes. There is nothing "unfair" about downvoting a question; no one is under any obligation to leave a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the event :

```
AddHandler StatusTimer.Tick, AddressOf StatusTimer_Tick
```

This line states that whenever Tick event occurs, your sub will be called.

However, if you want to use the `Handles` cause, you must declare your timer like this :

```
Dim WithEvents StatusTimer As New Timer()

'And your sub
Public Sub StatusTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StatusTimer.Tick
```

This method however does not allow you to remove the association. With AddHandler clause, you can remove an event listener by doing :

```
RemoveHandler StatusTimer.Tick, AddressOf StatusTimer_Tick
```

Comment: Thanks again SuperPeanut! Not the first time you've helped me out!

Comment: Or you need `With Events` on the declaration to enable `Handles` on the handler.

Comment: @Enigmativity Updated answer following your comment